# bootstrap panel class not getting applied

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

For some reason bootstraps panel class doesn't seem to be getting applied here:

```
<div class="container main-content">

      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-3">

          <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <img src="http://cliparts.co/cliparts/8TE/6jz/8TE6jzq9c.png" class="stats-image" />
<h3>ACHIEVERS</h3>
          </div>
            <div class="panel-body stats-body">
              <span class="stats-value">37%</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Plnkr here: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/7e3mXCDixuJ4U06lu3TX?p=info

what am i missing here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Bootstrap 4 alpha 2 which might not be having panel support. I couldn't find panel documentation here:

http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/alerts/

Instead, try using bootstrap 3.3.6 in the plunk

```
<link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.3.6" data-semver="3.3.6" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />
<link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.6" data-semver="3.3.6" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.js" />
```